# React Tabulator - Server side sorting, how to achieve?

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

I am using react tabulator https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tabulator in my application and I have a table where I need to do sorting but server side. How can I achieve this? I couldn't find anything on the internet. This is what my component looks like.

```
    <ReactTabulator
      ref={tableRef}
      options={tableOptions}
      columns={tableColumns}
      data={data ?? []}
      tooltips={true}
      layout={"fitDataFill"}
      rowClick={rowClick}
      rowFormatter={tableRowFormatter}
    />
```

I just need an event onSort where I can call the backend and update the data.